# How can I create a text input box with Pygame?

Tags: python, text, pygame, textinput

I want to get some text input from the user in Python and display what they are typing in a text box, and when they press enter, it gets stored in a string.

I've looked everywhere, but I just can't find anything. I'm using Pygame.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can define a [rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) as the area of the input box. If a `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs, use the `colliderect` method of the `input_box` rect to check if it collides with the `event.pos` and then activate it by setting a `active` variable to `True`.

If the box is active you can type something and Pygame will generate `pygame.KEYDOWN` events which have a `unicode` attribute that you can simply add to a string, e.g. `text += event.unicode`. If the user presses enter, you can do something with the `text` string (in the example I just print it) and reset it to `''`.

```
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 32)
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    input_box = pg.Rect(100, 100, 140, 32)
    color_inactive = pg.Color('lightskyblue3')
    color_active = pg.Color('dodgerblue2')
    color = color_inactive
    active = False
    text = ''
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
                if input_box.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    # Toggle the active variable.
                    active = not active
                else:
                    active = False
                # Change the current color of the input box.
                color = color_active if active else color_inactive
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if active:
                    if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                        print(text)
                        text = ''
                    elif event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                        text = text[:-1]
                    else:
                        text += event.unicode

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        # Render the current text.
        txt_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(200, txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        input_box.w = width
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(txt_surface, (input_box.x+5, input_box.y+5))
        # Blit the input_box rect.
        pg.draw.rect(screen, color, input_box, 2)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

---

Here's an object-oriented variant that allows you to easily create multiple input boxes:

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
COLOR_INACTIVE = pg.Color('lightskyblue3')
COLOR_ACTIVE = pg.Color('dodgerblue2')
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 32)


class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = COLOR_INACTIVE
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = FONT.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
            # Change the current color of the input box.
            self.color = COLOR_ACTIVE if self.active else COLOR_INACTIVE
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                    self.text = ''
                elif event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)

    def update(self):
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(200, self.txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        self.rect.w = width

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+5))
        # Blit the rect.
        pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)



def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    input_box1 = InputBox(100, 100, 140, 32)
    input_box2 = InputBox(100, 300, 140, 32)
    input_boxes = [input_box1, input_box2]
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

---

There are also third party modules available like [pygame_textinput](https://github.com/Nearoo/pygame-text-input).

Comment: It's better to use
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, screen.get_width/40)
Instead:
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 32)

Comment: Regarding the first code:
1) The section that starts`screen.fill((30, 30, 30))`, which incledes blitting, is executed unneccessarily a million tines! It should be aonly executed ig there's any change in the text.
2) Extending the input box accorfing to the text length is a very bad ide because it can go out of the window. No one does that. The size of text areas/boxes stays always the same for a certain activity. 
3) If the user clicks on the input box then it should **always** be active and toggled only if the user clicks outside the input box. 
Very inefficient code!

Comment: Passing the input box for the screen.fill() also would be better since there may be other components in the box.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `KEYDOWN` event to get the input from the keyboard (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)). The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object. `unicode` contains a single character string that is the fully translated character. Add the character to the text when a key is pressed.
Two special keys need to be dealt with. If <kbd>RETURN</kbd> is pressed, the input is finished. If <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> is pressed, the last character of the input text must be removed:

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TextInput](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TextInput#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
text = ""
input_active = True

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            input_active = True
            text = ""
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and input_active:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                input_active = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                text =  text[:-1]
            else:
                text += event.unicode

        window.fill(0)
        text_surf = font.render(text, True, (255, 0, 0))
        window.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Use the algorithm in a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) class. Handle the event in the `update` method.Determine whether the mouse clicks in the text entry field with [`collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) (see [How to detect when a rectangular object, image or sprite is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917346/how-to-detect-when-a-sprite-is-clicked/58935218#58935218)) and activate the text input box:

```py
class TextInputBox(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self, event_list):
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not self.active:
                self.active = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.active = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                self.render_text()
```

Pass the list of events to the `update` method of the *Group* that contains the *Sprite*:

```py
event_list = pygame.event.get()
for event in event_list:
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
group.update(event_list)
```

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteTextInput](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteTextInput#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

class TextInputBox(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, font):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.backcolor = None
        self.pos = (x, y) 
        self.width = w
        self.font = font
        self.active = False
        self.text = ""
        self.render_text()

    def render_text(self):
        t_surf = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.color, self.backcolor)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((max(self.width, t_surf.get_width()+10), t_surf.get_height()+10), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        if self.backcolor:
            self.image.fill(self.backcolor)
        self.image.blit(t_surf, (5, 5))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, self.color, self.image.get_rect().inflate(-2, -2), 2)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = self.pos)

    def update(self, event_list):
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not self.active:
                self.active = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.active = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                self.render_text()

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)

text_input_box = TextInputBox(50, 50, 400, font)
group = pygame.sprite.Group(text_input_box)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    group.update(event_list)

    window.fill(0)
    group.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can find a great module for Pygame text input [here](https://github.com/Nearoo/pygame-text-input).

I have been using it for a while and I really like it. A tutorial how to use it is included in the description.

However, I have added the possibility to draw a (coloured) rectangle around the text, by adding a **rect** and a **rect_color** parameter to the **_*init*_()* function and adding

```
if self.rect != None:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.rect_color, self.rect)    #screen is my pygame display surface
```

to the **update(self, events)** function.

Answer (score 5):

The [pygame_gui](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module allows you to create a text_input box from the user by creating a [UITextEntryLine](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pygame_gui.elements.html#module-pygame_gui.elements.ui_text_entry_line) instance. You'll need to set up an instance as in the [quick start guide](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html).

Create the text_input:

```py
from pygame.rect import Rect
from pygame_gui.elements.ui_text_entry_line import UITextEntryLine
text_input = UITextEntryLine(relative_rect=Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), manager=manager)
```

Get the text if enter is clicked:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
        if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_TEXT_ENTRY_FINISHED:
            if event.ui_element == text_input:
                entered_text = event.text
```

Comment: This is a really simple and easy solution if you can add a dependency on `pygame_gui`.

Only note, that in the example, the last line should actualy be `entered_text = event.text`

Answer (score 1):

I have written a class that can handle text input

minimal example:

```
import pygame as pg
from pgtextbox import pgtextbox
pg.init()

screen=pg.display.set_mode((1000,500))
textbox=pgtextbox(200,20)
textbox.insertAtCurser('Hallo')

while True:
    e = pg.event.wait(30000)
    if e.type == pg.QUIT:
        raise StopIteration

    textbox.addPgEvent(e)#uses keydown events
    
    print(textbox.text)

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(textbox.render(),(10,0))
    pg.display.flip()
pg.display.quit()
```

pgtextbox class:

```
import pygame as pg

class pgtextbox:#By K1521
    def __init__(self,width=100,height=10,fontname=None):
        self.surface=pg.Surface((width,height))
        self.text=""
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.font=pg.font.Font(fontname,pgtextbox.getMaxFontSize(fontname,lineheight=height))
        self.curserindex=0
        self.cursersurface=pg.Surface((self.font.size("|")[0]//2,self.font.size("|")[1]))
        self.cursersurface.fill((255,255,255))
        #self.cursersurface=self.font.render("|",False,(255,255,255),(0,0,0))
        self.offsety=int((height-self.font.get_linesize())/2)
        self.offsetx=0


    def curserpos(self):
        return self.font.size(self.text[:self.curserindex])[0]

    def addPgEvent(self,event):
        if event.type==pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                self.deleteAtCurser()
            elif event.key==pg.K_RIGHT:
                self.offsetCurser(1)
            elif event.key==pg.K_LEFT:
                self.offsetCurser(-1)
            else:
                self.insertAtCurser(event.unicode)

    def render(self):
        self.surface.fill((0,0,0))

        width=self.width-self.cursersurface.get_width()
        text=self.font.render(self.text,False,(255,255,255),(0,0,0))


        if self.curserindex>=0:
            curserpos=self.curserpos()+self.offsetx

            curserposnew=max(0,min(curserpos,width))
            self.offsetx+=curserposnew-curserpos
            curserpos=curserposnew
            #if curserpos<0:
                #self.offsetx-=curserpos
                #curserpos=0
            #if curserpos>width:
                #curserpos=curserpos-width
                #self.offsetx-=curserpos
        else:
            #self.offsetx=min(width-text.get_width(),0)
            self.offsetx=0

        self.surface.blit(text,(self.offsetx,self.offsety))
        if self.curserindex>=0:
            self.surface.blit(self.cursersurface,(curserpos,self.offsety))
            #print((curserpos,self.offsety))
        return self.surface

    def insertAtCurser(self,t):
        if self.curserindex<0:
            self.curserindex=len(self.text)
        self.text=self.text[:self.curserindex]+t+self.text[self.curserindex:]
        self.curserindex+=len(t)

    def deleteAtCurser(self,length=1):
        if self.curserindex<0:
            self.curserindex=len(self.text)

        newcurserindex=max(0,self.curserindex-length)
        self.text=self.text[:newcurserindex]+self.text[self.curserindex:]
        self.curserindex=newcurserindex

    def offsetCurser(self,i):
        self.curserindex=max(min(self.curserindex+i,len(self.text)),0)


    @staticmethod
    def longestline(self,fontname,lines):
        size=pg.font.Font(fontname,1000)
        return max(lines,key=lambda t:size(t)[0])

    @staticmethod
    def getMaxFontSize(fontname,width=None,lineheight=None,line=None):
        def font(size):
            return pg.font.Font(fontname,size)
        fontsize=float("inf")# inf

        if width:
            aproxsize=width*1000//font(1000).size(line)[0]
            while font(aproxsize).size(line)[0]<width:
                aproxsize+=1
            while font(aproxsize).size(line)[0]>width:
                aproxsize-=1
            fontsize=min(aproxsize,fontsize)

        if lineheight:
            aproxsize=lineheight*4//3
            while font(aproxsize).get_linesize()<lineheight:
                aproxsize+=1
            while font(aproxsize).get_linesize()>lineheight:
                aproxsize-=1
            fontsize=min(aproxsize,fontsize)
        return fontsize

    @staticmethod
    def rendermultilinetext(text,width=None,height=10,fontname=None,antialias=False,color=(255,255,255),background=None):
        if(len(text)-text.count("\n")==0):
            return pg.Surface((0,0))
        def font(size):
            return pg.font.Font(fontname,size)

        text=text.split("\n")
        fontsize=1000000000# inf

        longestline=None
        if height:
            longestline=pgtextbox.longestline(fontname,lines)
        fontsize=pgtextbox.getMaxFontSize(fontname,width,lineheight,longestline)

        font=font(fontsize)
        width=font.size(longestline)[0]
        lineheight=font.get_linesize()
        heigth=len(text)*lineheight
        textsurface=pg.Surface((width,heigth))
        if background:
            textsurface.fill(background)
        for i,line in enumerate(text):
            textsurface.blit(font.render(line,antialias,color,background),(0,i*lineheight))
        return textsurface
```