# How do I make a text box in pygame?

Tags: python, textbox, pygame

So I’m new with pygame and I was wondering how do you make a basic text box

I know you have to create a window as so:

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

screen= pygame.display.set_mode([800,600]) 
pygame.display.flip
```

but then I have no idea where to go from there

any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390412/6220679).

Answer (score 1):

PyGame is low-level library and it doesn't have widgets.

You can use other modules like [PGU](https://github.com/parogers/pgu), [OcempGUI](http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/gui.html) or [SGC](https://program.sambull.org/sgc/). Most of them have examples.

Most of them use own event loop so you have to learn how to use it instead of loop `while True:`.

See more on PyGame page:

- https://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui
- https://www.pygame.org/tags/gui

---

BTW:

`SGC` doesn't use own event loop and it shows how to use it in own mailoop in [Getting Started](https://program.sambull.org/sgc/tutorial.get_started.html)

`PGU` uses own event loop but it shows how to use it in own mainloop (only) in  [example 10](https://github.com/parogers/pgu/blob/master/examples/gui10.py)