# Delete multiple characters while holding backspace in Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a project and I found this code for a text box in Python:
[How to create a text input box with pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390231/how-to-create-a-text-input-box-with-pygame)

Now, I want to change the code so that **while** the user holds backspace the text box will delete characters.

I tried to change the code to this:

```
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if self.active:
        if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
            self.text = ''
        if event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
            while pg.KEYDOWN is pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                print "shock"
                self.text = self.text[:-1]
        else:
            self.text += event.unicode
        # Re-render the text.
        self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)
```

but it does not work and I can't find any solutions online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [keyboard repeat](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat), so holding down a key will generate multiple key down events.

So call `pg.key.set_repeat(500, 200)`, after `pg.init()`, to generate a backspace key down event every 200 milliseconds after an initial delay of half a second.

Comment: Thank you!! but where do I paste the code? I mean, do I need to delete the while? or the if or keep both

Comment: `pg.key.set_repeat` should be called after `pygame.init()`. Remove your while loop, and just truncate the `text` variable.

Comment: No worries, glad to be able to help.