# Why does import pygame_textinput doesn't work?

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried using import pygame_textinput to call the pygame_textinput module. It doesn't work though. I got it from [here](http://%20https://github.com/Nearoo/pygame-text-input).

Which was provided by another Stack Overflow page to get information about the `pygame_textinput` module as such:

[How to create a text input box with pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390231/how-to-create-a-text-input-box-with-pygame)

Just in case, I have tried getting it from the net as it is stated to be a third-party module but to no avail. I wrote the code in python shell as such:

```
import pygame_textinput
```

And got error message as such:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in module

import pygame_textinput

ImportError: No module named pygame_textinput
```

Help? (PS. The word module in the error message second line is actually covered in < >. I deleted it as couldn't show.

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install it ? https://pypi.org/project/textinput/

```
pip install pygame_textinput
```

guide how to install pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/