# Input in Python Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to create an input box in the main menu in my game to enter a player nickname and I can't find any libraries or other method to do this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46390231/6486738

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but the input() function allows user input.

For example:

```
print('Enter your nickname: ')
nm = input()
print('Hello, ' + nm)
```

Comment: :D but it's not console app, I need to make some box for example pygame.Rect(50, 100, 200, 50) but with possibility to type in

Comment: You cannot use the `input` function in an GUI application, as it blocks the application.

Comment: But for sure there is some way to create some kind of input box

Comment: I think you need to use get_text() to get the input of the user. First, create a text input object, and then use the update method to check when the user has given an answer. Something like that