# Why is pygame preventing my code from working

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a rock paper scissors game, and I'm using pygame to display some images, and depending on where I put my loop to have pygame open, pygame will either not respond, or my code won't continue

```
    import random
    import pygame

    pygame.init()
    width=400
    height=400
    dis=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.update

    running=True
    while running:
         for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                running=False
    pygame.quit()
    readyToPlay=input("Are you ready? y or n ")
```

Comment: You cannot mix a pygame event loop with `input`. `input` waits for an input. Hence the application loop will not response when you call `inpu` in the loop. When you call `input` after the loop, then you have to terminate the loop, before the input.

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: @MEdwin I don't get an error message, my code wouldn't run after that point, now I got a picture on pygame and my code runs, but pygame won't respond

Comment: @Rabbid76 If I broke the loop would pygame keep responding?

Comment: @Lucas_Not_Smart Pygame will wait and do nothing as long the input is not done. Some systems may even crash (it depends on the OS).

Comment: @Rabbid76 that does make sense, how am I able to keep the input and have pygame keep running?

Comment: See [Pygame Window not Responding after few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830453/pygame-window-not-responding-after-few-seconds/64832291#64832291) or [How to create a text input box with pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390231/how-to-create-a-text-input-box-with-pygame/64613666#64613666)

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you so much, I will look into these