# Pygame window crashing on run

Tags: python, pygame, crash, game-development

I am trying to make a hangman game that has a window which shows the hangman being drawn every time you make a wrong guess.. i am using pygame library for it but when i run the program it opens the window and then crashes. How to fix?

Here's the code:

```
import pygame

def wait():
    result=None
    import msvcrt 
    result=msvcrt.getch()
    return result

window=pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
window.fill((0, 0, 0))

running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
    if running==False:
        pygame.quit()

    print ("Press any key to start a game")
    wait()

    Wrong=0
    Word=list(input("Give the hidden word"))
    Hidden=[]
    Guess=input("Guess a letter or the word")

    for j in range(len(Word)):
        Hidden.append("_")

    if Guess in Word:
        for i in range(len(Word)):
            if Guess==Word[i]:
                Hidden.pop(i)
                Hidden.insert(i,Guess)
                print (Hidden)
    else:
        Wrong+=1

    if Wrong==1:
        White=pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),[300, 80], 50, 3)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif Wrong==2:
        Blue=pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 0, 255),[300, 130],[300, 350], 3)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif Wrong==3:
        Green=pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 255, 0),[300, 200],[400, 300], 3)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif Wrong==4:
        Red=pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 0, 0),[300, 200],[200, 300], 3)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif Wrong==5:
        Cyan=pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 255, 255),[300, 350],[200, 500], 3)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif Wrong==6:
        Yellow=pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 255, 255),[300, 350],[400, 500], 3)
        pygame.display.update()
    elif Wrong==7:
        print ("You Lost")
```

Comment: It is crashing due to the use of the `input` function. When calling the `input` function, the program waits until the user enters something. While it is waiting for input, it doesn't check for events in the pygame window, which causes the window to not respond and crash. I see that you aren't using the pygame window for anything, so why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every pygame program needs pygame.init() at the beginning
2. Use pygame.display.update() only once at the end of the program
3. Your program freezes because input() breaks the main loop of your program

Pygame start file:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    #Your code...

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

You can solve this by adding an input box to the pygame window: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390412/15500012

I hope it will help you, Adam