# Adding a text input field in PyGame Zero?

Tags: pgzero

Is it possible to add a text input field into a Pygame Zero game? I can't see it in the docs but may have overlooked it.

Comment: You have to implement it all yourself. I think it is very hard to do this i pygame zero. I only know a pygame implementation: [How to create a text input box with pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390231/how-to-create-a-text-input-box-with-pygame/64613666#64613666)

Answer (score 0):

Pygame is made to be very minimal. But there are libraries like [pygame-gui](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that implement common UI-utilities and -elements like the [UITextEntryLine](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pygame_gui.elements.html#module-pygame_gui.elements.ui_text_entry_line).

It might not be compatible with pgzero. In that case you can still look at the pygame-gui source code to understand, how text-entry might be implemented.

For example it is a bit more than just reacting to global key-down events but also about tracking the focused element so that the right element gets the text as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390231/how-to-create-a-text-input-box-with-pygame/64613666#64613666).